# What long-lasting (production-quality) tactile buttons work with RPi 3?

Tags: gpio, power

We are assembling a system that requires buttons to be placed upside down.
Our first attempt used [tactile buttons](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1010) mounted on a breadboard and stuck upside down, but the buttons keep falling out.

So, we are looking for a more "stable" tactile button system. I came across [these buttons](https://www.mcmaster.com/#standard-push-button-pilot-switches/=15geqwo), but I don't much about voltage and resistance, so I don't know if they will work.

Specifically: the Raspberry Pi 3 GPIO pins are 3.3V. The buttons are:

> Rated 6 amps @ 120 volts AC and 2.5 amps @ 24 volts DC with a maximum voltage of 600 AC and DC

Will these work together?
More generally, what is the right way to think about voltage, wattage, and resistance?

Comment: Those switches should work fine based on the DC operating range quoted. However, the idea of a breadboard and production quality do not really align . Something like this [permaproto board](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1606) from Adafruit is a better long term solution. The holes are wired together exactly like a breadboard, but allows soldering the components to the board, for a more permanent solution.

Comment: Per the [help center](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) shopping questions are explicitely off-topic.

Comment: @Jacobm001 apologies, I wasn't aware. I was looking for compatible products. Feel free to close/delete if necessary.

Comment: @JasonShah: It's been pointed out to me that a portion of your question is in fact on topic. Asking if something specific is compatible is on topic, but asking a general shopping question like "what is available", isn't. Editing your question may better reflect the portion that is allowed.

Comment: *Asking for specific purchasing recommendations.* is off-topic, asking if the item you've picked with its particular specifics fits your task is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Those buttons will do fine.**

Note that the listed ratings for the buttons are maximum or "absolute maximum" values that should not be exceeded. Operating them at the Pi and 3.3 V of its GPIO pins is well within the voltage rating. The current required to toggle an input pin is in the milliampere range or even below - so again, well within the limits of the buttons.

> Rated 6 amps @ 120 volts AC and 2.5 amps @ 24 volts DC with a maximum voltage of 600 AC and DC